# SWT Table not showing Tool tip in Windows 8 machine on mouse hover

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I simply use following code to set tool tip on a SWT table on mouse hover:-

```
table.setToolTipText("Tool Tip Demo");
```

But no tool tip is displyed on Windows 8 machine.But the same code works fine for me on WindowsXP. Why is this difference happening?How can I resolve this issue?Pls explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Windows 8 bug, AFAIK. You should either wait for a new SWT release, and/or file a bug for the SWT guys. The good thing is, it's not a blocker bug. :-)

Try a workaround, like setting tooltips on the columns/column headers.

You could even try *fake tooltips* [as presented here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CreatefaketooltipsforitemsinaSWTtable.htm).